# How to pass HTML as String to a TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a table that the users edits with the property `contenteditable="true"` but I don't want to this come at the output.

So to output I'm doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    var text = $("#tab").html(); // taking the content
    var res = text.replace('<td contenteditable="true">','<td>'); //trying to replace   
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = res ; //output data
  });
});
```

The problem is that the code is ignoring the replace, do you know why ?

====
Edit:

Sorry guys i think i wasn't clear at all. The only problem is with the OUTPUT, not the html, i'm passing the html to a text area to the users copy and etc.

Please take a look at the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mnpxwhx6/

When i do the Output i don't want to the TDs carries the Editable atribute.

Thanks

Comment: `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: textarea elements hold a value, not innerHTML content so as `squint` has posted, use `.value`

Comment: Why not use `document.getElementById("yourTd").contentEditable = true;` instead of doing a replace?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's ignoring the replace? Are you saying you get the original HTML? Something else? Have you verified the value of `text` matches what you're targeting exactly? Did you mean nothing shows up at all in the textarea?

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question ? What is the purpose of using `.replace()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If interpret Question correctly, `.replace()` is not necessary ? If you want to remove `contenteditable` attribute at `td` element you can clone `#tab` element use [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr) to remove `contenteditable` from `html` of `td` elements before setting `html` of `textarea`

```css
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn").click(function() {
        var text = $("#tab").clone();
        text.find("td[contenteditable]").each(function() {
          $(this).removeAttr("contenteditable")
        })
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text[0].innerHTML;
      });
      delete text;
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="tab">
    <table border=1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            48-50
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            50-52
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            52-54
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>medida1</th>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            104cm
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            108cm
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            112cm
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>medida2</th>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            106cm
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            110cm
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            114cm
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>medida3</th>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            122cm
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            126cm
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            130cm
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>medida4</th>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            69cm
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            70cm
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            71cm
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>medida5</th>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            38cm
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            40cm
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            42cm
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

  <button id="btn">Show HTML</button>
  <hr>

  <textarea id="output" rows="4" cols="50">

  </textarea>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mnpxwhx6/1/

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but I need the HTML structure, the problem is that i want to remove the string '<td contenteditable="true">' and change to '<td>' on the output.

Comment: @BrunoDantas See updated post. You should be able to use [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr)

Comment: @BrunoDantas See my answer. Your original HTML will remain in tact, and the string <td contenteditable="true"> gets replaced with <td>

Comment: Thanks for your help! That' was exactly what i want :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a regular expression to replace the string.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    var text = $("#tab").html(); // taking the content
    var res = text.replace(/^.*<td.*contenteditable="true".*>$/gm,'<td>'); 
    $("#output").text(res) ; //output data
  });
});
```

## Working Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/mnpxwhx6/2/

Comment: Does `document.getElementById("output")` have method `.html()` ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you wish to remove the `contenteditable=true` attribute from the `<td>`.

That is not the way to go about it.  Instead, try using the jQuery `select by attribute` selector to locate the desired TD and change the attribute:

```
$('table').find('[contenteditable=true]').attr('contenteditable','false');
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/kpg1Ldwr/)</kbd>

Comment: First, it should be .prop("contenteditable", null) to remove the attribute as per jQuery documentation. Secondly, I don't think this will work because I think the OP is trying to create a copy of the original HTML, make edits, and then add it to the output container. Your solution modifies the original html

Comment: Does `.attr('contenteditable','false')` remove `contenteditable` attribute from `html` ?

Comment: No, I was interrupted and could not finish my answer. But fortunately you had the correct solution in your answer with `.removeAttr()`. Upvoted.